# Rooting Android without Apps

Tags: rooting

Is it possible to root an android device ....

- Without using any third party applications like Kingo Root?
- Without Custom Recovery or Custom ROM?

If yes, please guide me, how to do?

Regards

GNS

Comment: What device? The process varies a lot based on which device and the version of Android... the only "generic" way that works on most devices with an unlocked bootloader is boot/flash a custom recovery (many devices allow you to BOOT recovery without actually flashing it) and flash SuperSU, but again it depends on your device.

Comment: Thank you replying. My android tablet is iBall Brace-X1 which is Android 4.4.2, Kernel version: iBall3.4.67, MT6592, RAM 2GB and internal storage is 16GB. I am unable to unlock its boot-loader.

Comment: The only way I know for "generic" MediaTek devices is via https://androidmtk.com/download-mtk-droid-tool

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a lots of rooting method. Also per device have different rooting method. Anyway expect recovery, rooting app etc. you can root your device with adb too. [Here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2684210) is a universal manual root method by adb.